# Where do I find gazebo message structure?

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I need to know how does the msgs::SonarStamped message look like, but can't find it in documentation. How can I find it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/21368/where-do-i-find-gazebo-message-structure?/) by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 755 on 2018-12-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Here's the documentation for all messages: http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/msg-api/9.0.0/classes.html

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on 2018-12-11**:
Thank you. I can't really find the structure of the message. Does it really not exist anywhere? Can I get it other way like ROS messages with `rosmsg show`?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-12-11**:
Oh you're right, the documentation looks really bad: http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/msg-api/9.0.0/sonar__stamped_8proto.html

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-12-11**:
Here's the source code: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/gazebo9/gazebo/msgs/sonar_stamped.proto

**Comment by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on 2018-12-13**:
Thank you! The source code was sufficient to get the information I needed.